# Linux command to verify which switch is connected to each machine

Tags: linux, networking

Good morning,

On three different servers, I want to check the name of the switches connected to these servers. I would perform this with a Linux command if it's possible, or maybe with some kind information found in the configuration files if they're present. My final goal is to check if 3 of the machines of our server farm are connected to a single switch or two (having, in this case, High Availability). Is it possible using a specific Linux command or to list info in a specific configuration networking file?

Many thanks in advance

Stefano

I found on the Internet this command: `cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0` but it has not been useful

```
cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0 of Linux Centos commands
```

With the command `cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0`, I have `no Output`. I would have some typical Linux output lines to analyze if a switch code or switch name is present

Comment: Switches are transparent devices. Only managed switches may have a name, and the management interface may be on a completely different network; unmanaged switches will not have names.

Answer (score 0):

`traceroute` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) shows the network path from Point A to Point B.  You can run it from your desktop to each server, and see if the last hop to each is identical.

Comment: That counts router hops because routers decrement the IP TTL. Switches are transparent devices that do not alter the IP packet, and even do not know or care if the frame payload is IPv4, IPv6, IPX, AppleTalk, etc. Ethernet has nothing like TTL.

Comment: @RonMaupin You're right.  More work would be required.

Comment: Many thanks to the people who answered. If I understand well, I have to execute the command traceroute from my desktop. From MobaXterm I can access with ssh to each of three server that are the object of the analysis and for each one verify if the last hop is identical and in this way the 3 machines are linked to the same switch?